# Sorting by key > 10 integer sequences. with thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

I want to perform a `sort_by_key` where I have a single key-sequence
and multiple value sequences.

One usually performs this with

```
sort_by_key(
             key, 
             key + N, 
             make_zip_iterator(
                                make_tuple(x1 , x2 , ...)
                               )
            )
```

However I want to perform a sort with > 10 sequences each of length N. Thrust does not support
tuples of size >= 10. So is there a way around this ?

Of course one can keep a separate copy of the `key` vector and perform 
sorts on bunches of 10 sequences.  But I would like to do everything in a single call.

Comment: How many values per tuple do you need, exactly?

Comment: I need 12 elements in a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thrust::tuple` is hardcoded to always have 10 elements, so there isn't a direct way to form a `zip_iterator` from more than ten individual iterators, and therefore no way of sorting more than 10 distinct iterators by key in a single fused operation (and implicitly no way of passing more than 10 iterators into a user functor as well).

If you really can't think of a useful way to combine some of the individual vectors into a single iterator (for example form a vector of tuple values), then one alternative might be to use permutation iterators. If you create an array from a counting iterator and sort that, so something like:

```
device_vector<int> indices(N);
copy(make_counting_iterator(0), make_counting_iterator(N), indices.begin());
sort_by_key(key, key+N, indices);
```

`indices` now holds ordered indices into the vectors you would otherwise have sorted. You can then create a permutation iterator which can be used to "gather" the input data by your key as part of subsequent algorithm calls. You can make as many permutation iterators as needed, and they can be permutations of zip iterators to providing different "views" of the 12 input iterators as you need them in subsequent code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may use the simple "scatter" operation. Perform only one "thrust::sort_by_key" operation, then for each data vector apply "thrust::scatter" operation. The values will be distributed to according locations.

```
thrust::sequence(indices.begin(), indices.end());
thrust::sort_by_key(keyvals.begin(), keyvals.end(), indices.begin());

//now indices keep the locations of the sorted key values
foreach ( ... ) {
    thrust::scatter(data.begin(), data.end(), indices.begin(), sorteddata.begin());
}
```

Gather and scatter operations are quite powerful and opens many opportunities.

Comment: Your second code snippet is functionally identical to the accepted answer I proposed. I don't understand the nomenclature in the first code. How do `indices` and `sorteddata` relate to the original question?

Comment: I made some updates on the answer. Actually because the scatter operation is not in-place (isn't it?) we need another vector to hold the output. Storing the result at another vector may lead better coalescing if the values will be accessed sequentially in proceeding operations? Otherwise yes, using permutation iterators is a better choice :)